# VBA Complicated Getter, Setter syntax

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm rather new to VBA I need to create an object with relativelly complicated Getter and Setter. To do this I am constantly checking with [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzh9ha57.aspx) but clearly I am not understanding something because VBE keep highlighting lines starting and closing: Property (it appaently needs Get or Let??), Get(it apparently needs  identifier), Let(it apparently needs  identifier as well).

But I am trying to follow more concise notation where Get and Let methods are within a Property Statement which is used by Microsoft in its examples(see link above).

Can someone tell me where is my syntax wrong(or Microsoft's Documentation for that matter)???

Thank you

```
Private Matrix() As Vector
Property Transition()
    Public Get(Old_S As String, New_S As String, Period As Integer) As Double
        ' Some Code
        Return Matrix(Column, Row).Value(Period)
    End Get
    Public Let(Old_S As String, New_S As String, Vector_String As String)
        ' Some Code
        Matrix(Row, Column).Value = Vector_String
    End Let
End Property
```

Comment: Please do not use the VB.NET tag for questions related to VBA.  They are completely different technologies.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that Sorry

Comment: No problem.  It's an honest mistake.  Just don't let it happen again :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are reading the documentation for VB.NET.  That's why you are confused.  The syntax for properties in VBA is different.  In VBA, the `Get` and `Let` for a property are not grouped together.  They need to be listed separately, essentially like two separate methods:

```
Private mMyProperty As String

Public Property Get MyProperty() As String
    MyProperty = mMyProperty
End Property

Public Property Let Transition(Value As String)
    mMyProperty = Value
End Property
```

For VBA reference material, try starting [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are reading .Net help files! :)

Assuming you have a valid Vector class, your properties need to bde defined like this:

```
Private Matrix()              As Vector
Public Property Get Transition(Old_S As String, New_S As String, Period As Integer) As String
' Some Code
    Transition = Matrix(Column, Row).Value(Period)
End Property
Public Property Let Transition(Old_S As String, New_S As String, Period As Integer, Vector_String As String)
' Some Code
    Matrix(Row, Column).Value = Vector_String
End Property
```

Note that the argument list for both procedures must match except that the Letter has an additional argument of the same type that the Getter returns.

It is also slightly unusual to have a Getter property that accepts arguments in VBA - that would more usually be implemented as a method.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using VB.Net syntax in VBA. That's not going to work, as they're entirely different languages. Here is a link to the proper documentation for the [VBA Property Keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278574.aspx).

Here is how you would write it in VBA.

```
Private Matrix() As Vector
Public Property Get MatrixValue(Old_S As String, New_S As String, Period As Integer) As Double
    ' Some Code
    MatrixValue = Matrix(Column, Row).Value(Period)
End Property

Public Property Let MatrixValue(Old_S As String, New_S As String, Vector_String As String)
    ' Some Code
    Matrix(Row, Column).Value = Vector_String
End Property
```

But you're going to have trouble with the `Get` property. You *can* [pass parameters into `Get`](http://vba4all.com/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-arguments-in-the-letget-properties-on-a-class-module-in-vba/), but it's not exactly intuitive. I think what you're really looking for is a function.

```
Public Function GetMatrixValue(Old_S As String, New_S As String, Period As Integer) As Double
    ' Some Code
    MatrixValue = Matrix(Column, Row).Value(Period)
End Function
```