# Setting a local Variable from a publicvariable on another form during form initialization

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to set an array during user form initialization. I am filling the array with Public variables created on another user form. The issue is, when I attempt to set the values in the array during form initialization they do not populate. If I use the same code with a button click it works like a charm.

The Code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Declare local Variables
Dim targetGrades(1 To 5) As String
'Set Variables
targetGrades(1) = frmSettingsSetup.g1
targetGrades(2) = frmSettingsSetup.g2
targetGrades(3) = frmSettingsSetup.g3
targetGrades(4) = frmSettingsSetup.g4
targetGrades(5) = frmSettingsSetup.g5

End Sub
```

When I run the code the variables are = "" as are the Public variables being pulled from frmSettingsSetup (g1-g5). Is there a way to call variables from another form during form initialization?

Comment: Why not use getters and setters? See the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257127/vba-complicated-getter-setter-syntax) question.

Comment: is `frmSettingsSetup` open when you are initializing the other form? if not then it wont get any value as there is none. Forms are Classes, show if its not open, there's no instance value to get.

Comment: frmSettingsSetup is hidden but not closed `frmSettingsSetup.Hide` when I initialize the other form.

Comment: just put `msgbox frmSettingsSetup.g1` in the initialize and see what value comes back.

Comment: When I add that code the message box returns the correct value. I can Create a Variable and it assigns the correct value to a variable, but when I attempt to fill an array as I did above each item is left blank.

Comment: How / when are you looking to see what values have been placed in `targetGrades(1)` - are you looking in the `Watch` window while stepping through the code, or are you looking at the value when used somehow in some other piece of code.  (Remember that you have defined `targetGrades` to only be in scope within `UserForm_Initialize`, so that array will not be available outside that subroutine.)

Comment: You also say in your question "the variables are = "" as are the Public variables being pulled from frmSettingsSetup (g1-g5)." but an earlier comment says "When I add that code the message box returns the correct value." - those statements seem to be contradictory.

Comment: I am calling it in a function that is being called within the subroutine.  I Attempted to move the array out of the function and it is working just fine. Is it possible to use an array called in a subroutine within a function called within the same subroutine?

Comment: If you want a variable to be accessible to all functions/subroutines within a module, you should declare the variable prior to the first function/subroutine in that module.  If you declare it using `Dim` (or `Private`) it will be accessible to all functions/subroutines within that module, but not to other modules.  If you declare it using `Public` it will be accessible to other modules in your project as well.

Comment: Thank you, To resolve this I created a Module called Globals and declared my global variables there. This makes it possible to access the variable regardless of form status.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I created a Module called Globals and declared my global variables there. This makes it possible to access the variable regardless of form status.